# library not found for -lNSLogger after using use_frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to import a swift library into my Objective C program so I need to use the command use_frameworks! inside the podfile. But when I place it I get the following error:

> Ld
>   /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myTarget.app/myTarget
>   normal arm64
>       cd "/Users/user1/Desktop/Projects/BitBucket/myapp-Ios-2/myapp "
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CocoaLumberjack
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NSLogger
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/QRCodeReaderViewController
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCDLumberjackNSLogger
>   -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCDYouTubeKit
>   -F/Users/user1/Desktop/Projects/BitBucket/myapp-Ios-2/myapp/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS
>   -F/Users/user1/Desktop/Projects/BitBucket/myapp-Ios-2/myapp/Pods/Fabric/iOS
>   -F/Users/user1/Desktop/Projects/BitBucket/myapp-Ios-2/myapp/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/user1/Desktop/Projects/BitBucket/myapp-Ios-2/myapp/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/user1/Desktop/Projects/BitBucket/myapp-Ios-2/myapp/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/user1/Desktop/Projects/BitBucket/myapp-Ios-2/myapp/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks
>   -filelist /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myTarget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myTarget.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip
>   -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myTarget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myTarget_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myTarget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myTarget.swiftmodule
>   -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework CocoaLumberjack -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework
>   FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework
>   FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework
>   GoogleToolboxForMac -framework MBProgressHUD -framework NSLogger
>   -framework Protobuf -framework QRCodeReaderViewController -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework
>   UIKit -framework XCDLumberjackNSLogger -framework XCDYouTubeKit -ObjC
>   -lNSLogger -lXCDLumberjackNSLogger -lXCDYouTubeKit -framework CFNetwork -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MediaPlayer -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics
>   -framework Foundation -framework MapKit -lsqlite3 -framework Pods_defaults_myTarget -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myTarget.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myTarget_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ethzfdlmiblbkqdggndnysapvskv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myTarget.app/myTarget
>
> ld: library not found for -lNSLogger clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I have tried so far and didn't work:

1. Target/Build Settings ::  Enable Bitcode: NO
2. File/Workspace Settings/Derived Data Arrow :: Delete DerivedData folder, empty trash
3. Target/Build Settings/Test Host :: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/TargetName.app/TargetName
4. Terminal :: pod deintegrate , pod install
5. Clear, rebuild

Here is my podfile:

```
use_frameworks!



platform :ios, '8.0'

abstract_target 'defaults' do


pod 'XCDYouTubeKit', '~> 2.5.3'
pod 'XCDLumberjackNSLogger', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'QRCodeReaderViewController', '~> 4.0.2'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.6'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.1'
pod 'NSLogger'


 target 'myApp'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by doing this:

> Target/Build Settings/Other Linker Flags :: Remove NSLogger library